# GET AUTO_INCREMENT VALUE using sql without using the max(id) or previous id or row count

Tags: mysql

Help
How to get auto_increment value of database table using sql without using the max(id) or previous id or row count in mysql

Answer (score 1):

use LAST_INSERT_ID() <sup>[DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)</sup> to get the last generated ID.

Answer (score 0):

Considet the table 'Student' having column 'Id' (Id is auto increment).Then,

```
select Id from Student order by Id desc LIMIT 1
```